# How to ignore \N escape when dropping rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, escaping

I have a data frame in Pandas that contains a column (data type = object) filled with \N values. I tried to drop the rows using the code below and received the unicode error.

```py
df = df.drop(df['birth_year'] == '\N')


 File "<ipython-input-17-91f65c6f54c3>", line 1
    df = df.drop(df['birth_year'] == '\N')
                                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: malformed \N character escape
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\N'` is an illegal character in Python, try lower-casing the values then drop the values, and also change the way you drop it, like:

```
df = df[df['birth_year'].str.lower() != '\n']
```

Comment: Putting the r in front of '\n' as @ALollz suggested worked! Thanks ya'll I really appreciate it!